# Using argparser in combination with questions to the user

Tags: python, argparse

so I am trying to make my code usable though `argparse` but I am expecting that most users are not so familiar with running something in a console. Is their a way that I would request the input through questions.

Like:

```
Please provide the path to the data:
/home/usr/...

What is the target variable? 
y
```

And so on, is that even possible with `argparser` or should I look for something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`argparse` only does command line arguments and doesn't support prompting the user, but it does make it easy to implement something like this. It supports optional arguments, and after parsing gives you a namespace object you can use. You just need to implement the prompting yourself and assign into the namespace.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('path', nargs='?')
parser.add_argument('target', nargs='?')
args = parser.parse_args()

print(args)

if args.path is None:
    args.path = input('Please provide the path to the data: ')

if args.target is None:
    args.target = input('What is the target variable? ')

print(args)
```

Test runs:

```
$ ./test.py /somepath spam  # All arguments provided
Namespace(path='/somepath', target='spam')
Namespace(path='/somepath', target='spam')

$ ./test.py /otherpath  # Forgotten "target"
Namespace(path='/otherpath', target=None)
What is the target variable? eggs
Namespace(path='/otherpath', target='eggs')

$ ./test.py  # No arguments provided
Namespace(path=None, target=None)
Please provide the path to the data: /anotherpath
What is the target variable? ham
Namespace(path='/anotherpath', target='ham')
```

If you have more than two parameters I'd recommend DRYing out the above code, something like this:

```
arg_prompts = [
    ('path', 'Please provide the path to the data: '),
    ('target', 'What is the target variable? '),
    ]

for arg, prompt in arg_prompts:
    if getattr(args, arg) is None:
        setattr(args, arg, input(prompt))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use input

```
import argparse

args = argparse.ArgumentParser()

args.name = input("enter your name:\n")

print("Your name is :\n",args.name)
```