# Is there a way to return the input values in different variables from self-defined function if the user doesn't input parameters in command-line form?

Tags: python, user-input, command-line-arguments, optparse

I am making a basic MAC changer application in Kali Linux that takes argument in the following form:

```
python mac_changer.py -i <interface> -m <new MAC address>
```

In PyCharm I have made the following functions that take the arguments and returns it, I can store the returned values that are parsed but I also want to allow program to ask user for interface and new MAC address in case the user does not input the interface and MAC in the command. I can return the parsed arguments in the form of **options** variable, I can also return the inputted arguments but is there any way to store the inputted arguments?
 *all the modules are properly imported and the following code is a part of the full program*

```
def get_arguments():
    parser = optparse.OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("-i", "--interface", dest="interface", help="Interface to change its MAC address")
    parser.add_option("-m", "--mac", dest="new_mac", help="New MAC address")
    (options, arguments) = parser.parse_args()
    if options.interface and options.new_mac:
        if not options.interface:
            #Code to handle error
            parser.error(("[-] Please specify an interface, use --help for more info"))
        elif not options.new_mac:
            #Code to handle error
            parser.error(("[-] Please specify a new MAC, use --help for more info"))
        return options
    else:
        return input("Inteface> "),input("New MAC> ")

options = get_arguments()
printf(options.interface)
printf(options.new_mac)
```

This outputs the given arguments from the above command line but I also want to store and use the arguments that code gets from the user using the **input** function alongside the parsed arguments.

Comment: Wow, OptionParser handles parameter given in command line, why do you add an `ìnput` to get the values  ? They are in `arguments` variable. Also the parser handles the error if you specfify required=True in the add_option

Comment: @azro I said that in case the user doesn't enters the parameter in the command line, I want the code to ask for the variables manually hence the reason for using the input function

Comment: FWIW I [answered a similar question about argparse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61148330/4518341), the module that supplanted optparse.

Comment: BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask] if you want advice. I edited your question's tags to better reflect what it's about.

Answer (score 0):

Your code basically works, but this is problematic because you have two different return types:

```
        return options  # argparse.Namespace object
    else:
        return input("Inteface> "),input("New MAC> ")  # tuple of two strings

options = get_arguments()
printf(options.interface)
printf(options.new_mac)
```

If you use a type checker on this code and annotate the return type, one or other of these lines will raise an error.  If you return `options` as a tuple and the caller tries to access `options.interface`, it's going to raise an `AttributeError` because the tuple doesn't have a field called `interface`.

The easiest fix would be to just say that the function returns `interface` and `new_mac` as a string tuple in either case:

```
from typing import Tuple

def get_arguments() -> Tuple[str, str]:
    """Returns interface, new_mac args, either from command line or user input"""
    ...
```

and then:

```
        return options.interface, options.new_mac
    else:
        return input("Interface> "),input("New MAC> ")

interface, new_mac = get_arguments()
print(interface)
print(new_mac)
```

A slightly nicer solution IMO would be to use a `NamedTuple`, which is basically a tuple that you can give a name to, as well as names of its individual fields:

```
from typing import NamedTuple

class ChangerOptions(NamedTuple):
    interface: str
    new_mac: str

def get_arguments() -> ChangerOptions:

    ...

        return ChangerOptions(options.interface, options.new_mac)
    else:
        return ChangerOptions(input("Interface> "),input("New MAC> "))

options = get_arguments()
print(options.interface)
print(options.new_mac)
```

If you're forced to call a function that has no type annotations and multiple possible return types at runtime (i.e. you're using someone else's code and they're a terrible person who wants you to suffer), it's possible to deal with it in the calling code by doing something like:

```
        return options  # argparse.Namespace object
    else:
        return input("Inteface> "),input("New MAC> ")  # tuple of two strings


options = get_arguments()
try:
    # this will raise an AttributeError if no fields with these names
    interface, new_mac = options.interface, options.new_mac
except AttributeError:
    # whoops -- maybe it's a tuple?
    # this will raise a TypeError if that wasn't right either...
    interface, new_mac = options
print(interface)
print(new_mac)
```

Comment: thank you for the updated code but "->" is a python3 exclusive and if I am using raw_input instead of input, what should i replace that with?